# How to take screen shot of entire client machine not only web browser or a web page from javascript

Tags: javascript, screenshot, screen-capture

I want to capture the screenshot to a image not the video. I found ways to do that but they are either capturing the current web page or recoding the video from entire screen. I found [This library](https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/screen-recording-in-10-lines-of-vanilla-js-3bo8) to record screen. This is doing something similar which WebRTC does. My requirement is to just take an image of entire screen programmatically from my web application written in plain javascript. Is there any way I can do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MediaStream you get through the Media Capture and Streams API, you can create an [ImageCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture) instance and call its [`grabFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/grabFrame) method that will produce an ImageBitmap you'll be able to paint on a `<canvas>`.

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
const capture = new ImageCapture(track);
// when you need the still image
const bitmap = await capture.grabFrame();
// if you want a Blob version
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = bitmap.width;
canvas.height = bitmap.height;
canvas.getContext("bitmaprenderer").transferFromImageBitmap(bitmap);
const blob = await new Promise((res) => canvas.toBlob(res));
```

Now, I should note that this ideal path is currently only accessible to Chromium based browsers.
For other browsers you'd need to set the `srcObject` of an HTMLVideoElement to the MediaStream, and to `drawImage` that HTMLVideoElement on a 2D context.

Comment: that `stream.getVideoTracks()` gives an error: `Uncaught TypeError: mediaStream.getVideoTracks is not a function`

Comment: @Kevin did you correctly `await` for the Promise to resolve? What does `console.log(mediaStream)` outputs?

Comment: Literally just ran it again and no errors? odd, I tried it several times and it simply didn't work. Thank you for that! One last thing, does this await to blob take a long time?

Comment: Thank you. I am having difficulties sending this blob over socketio. it seems to take a long time when sending the blob, but when creating the blob and sending a long string it is fast. This is why I thought maybe it is taking a while to generate the blob.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread, to generate the Blob it should take about no time at all.

Comment: Thank you I will keep trying to see what the issue is. running it in a loop gives me `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The associated Track is in an invalid state` I will look into it further thanks again!